# Translation help needed

Tags: translation

I am doing some DIY and stumbled upon blog that should aid me in figuring out details of some obscure electronic PCB.

Google translate was useful for most of the text but I am not able to translate image part with it.

I would be grateful for any help in translating text on this image (esp. parts 1 and 2):

[image]

The [blog post itself](https://blog.cirias.li/trackpoint-pinout/) (for context).

Comment: use online translators:

２。这两个里面应该有至少一个是滤波电容｜看一下哪个有一端是和 GND 连着的，它的另外一端就应该是 VCC
１。晶震，这种封装中间是 GND
３。因为是模拟输出设备，很有可能这四个角是 VCC，GND，X，Y 可以根据这个和上面的再次确认
 
find Images for 晶震 on web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) One of the two must be "Filter capacitor"(滤波电容), Look which one has a side that connects to "GND" well, the other side of it must be "VCC".

1) "crystal oscillator"(晶震) , in the middle of it is "GND".

3) Because it is "Analog output device"(模拟输出设备), it is very likely that the 4 corners are "VCC","GND","X","Y", Based on this, check with above to make sure.